# detect the appear and disappear of international keyboard

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard-events

When a keyboard appears, is there a way to detect that it's an international keyboard (with an extra ribbon on top of normal keyboard to show the international characters) and also get it's frame size? I need to use that info to move upward (if needed) the view above the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this article: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard/

It addresses most of your questions.  In addition to notifications, text views will become or resign 'first responder' which will bring up or hide a keyboard view.

As for whether or not the keyboard shows international characters, I'm not really sure how to do that.  However, if you get the frame size of the keyboard (as described in the tutorial) you can adjust your view accordingly assuming that this was your concern.

**UPDATE**

Also check out: [Keyboard resize event in iOS 5 (Chinese keyboard bug)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411151/keyboard-resize-event-in-ios-5-chinese-keyboard-bug)