# How to detect hide event of international keyboard? iOS

Tags: ios

How to detect hide event of international keyboard? 
`UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` doesn't seem to trigger.

Below related link is not helpful.

[detect the appear and disappear of international keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073795/detect-the-appear-and-disappear-of-international-keyboard)

**MORE INFO**

This is how I setup notification for both `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"keyboardDidShow");
}
-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"keyboardDidHide");
}
```

`keyboardDidShow` is triggered twice. First is when *standard* keyboard pops out. Second is when the *international* keyboard pops out.

`keyboardDidHide` is NOT triggered when I hide the *international* keyboard. But it is triggered when *standard* keyboard is hidden.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Same to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` ? How did you setup your notification?

Comment: Seems right, you can take a try with `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` instead `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`.

Comment: Ney, I did. UIKeyboardWillHideNotification didn't work. But obviously there's a way to do this because all major messaging apps are able to detect this, ie adjust visible area when international keyboard triggers. Just not sure how they do it.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/05/the-ipad-split-keyboard-and-missing-notifications.html). The main idea is to use `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to adapt your UI when the keyboard frame changes.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right handle. Been looking for this. You want to repost this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any notification if the user changes keyboards. Only if the keyboard appears or disappears.

Only solution I know of would be to observe or react to changes (Try KVO?) on

```
[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage
```

See also: [Detecting current iPhone input language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language)

Comment: currentInputMode is deprecated in ios 7

Comment: There is an undocumented notification `UIKeyboardLayoutDidChangedNotification` (sic) that you might want to try to listen too.

Comment: Also there is `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` which you might want to try or observing the `+activeInputModes` property of `UITextInputMode`.